# has anyone used hazelcast with play framework 2.0

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, hazelcast

Has anyone used Hazelcast (preferably 2.1) with play framework 2.0/2.1 (not 1.2+)?
I am getting exceptions while trying to use the versions mentioned above (I was not able to run play install for hazelcast - gave a 'not a valid key error' as the response).
My project reference the hazelcast jar files - I tried adding a reference to Hazelcast in the dependencies.yml file as well but to no avail.

Any suggestions except moving back to 1.2 would be quite welcome.  If there is no other way, I will revert to play 1.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reverted to using hazelcast in play 1.2.3.

Comment: update - using it now but not using any play framework modules

Comment: there are issues/workarounds for class loaders when using hazelcast 3+ with play2+ as of now.